# Position on Node After Rotation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, coordinates, coordinate-systems

Okay so I have a node that's node.size is a (5,5) rectangle. Its position is (100,100), and its anchor point is the default (0.5, 0.5).

I tried to find the point at the farthest right, but still centre Y. Naturally this returned the point (102.5, 100). This is perfect. I found the point by simply using `CGPointMake(node.position + node.size.width/2, node.position);`

This works great, but the thing is I want to rotate the node while still knowing what that point is. I was wondering if their was some kind of math I could perform using the nodes zRotation in order to find the new point (the same point on the nodes frame) after the rotation.

To make it clear I want to know where the point that is originally 102.5, 100, is after the node rotates.

Thank you all very much in advance for all of your answers

Comment: look for "rotate point around circle/radius" or simply add a node a that position as child of the other node, then rotate the other node and you get the child's position after the rotation

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, that is exactly what I have been doing thus far. I will look into the rotate point around circle/radius, but for now I have just been attaching a child node at the point within the parent. I was just wondering if their was an easier, cpu intensive process than creating a new node each time I require it. Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let *r* be the distance from the anchor point of the sprite to the point of interest. In your case,

```
r = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) = 2.5;
```

where *dx* = 2.5 and *dy* = 0.

Also, let theta be the rotation angle, which is initially zero. We now have a point in polar coordinates, (*r*, *theta*), that represents the point (2.5, 0). We can now rotate the point about the sprite's anchor point by changing theta. After rotating the sprite, we convert (*r*, *theta*) to cartesian coordinates by

```
x = r * cos(theta);
y = r * sin(theta);
```

and add the sprite's position to convert the point to scene coordinates.

```
x = x + sprite.position.x;
y = y + sprite.position.y;
```

**EDIT:** I think this is what you are trying to implement.

```
@interface MyScene()

@property SKSpriteNode *object1;
@property SKSpriteNode *object2;

@end

@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if(self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        _object1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(10,5)];
        _object1.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
        [self addChild:_object1];
        SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration: 2.5f];
        SKAction *rotate = [SKAction rotateByAngle:3*M_PI/4 duration:2.0f];
        SKAction *addObject = [SKAction runBlock:^{
            _object2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(10,5)];

            _object2.zRotation = _object1.zRotation;

            CGFloat dx = _object1.size.width / 2;
            CGFloat dy = 0;
            CGFloat r = sqrtf(dx*dx + dy*dy);
            CGFloat x = r*cosf(_object1.zRotation);
            CGFloat y = r*sinf(_object1.zRotation);

            _object2.position = CGPointMake(_object1.position.x + 2*x, _object1.position.y + 2*y);

            [self addChild:_object2];
        }];
        SKAction *seq = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, rotate, addObject]];
        [_object1 runAction:seq];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much. I didn't understand it at first, but the instant I researched polar coordinates it all made perfect sense. Thank you very much once again, I think this will work perfectly for what I require.

Comment: You are totally right. The major problem was that I was including the objects frame height in the Pythagorean theorem equation when I was really was suppose to set it to 0, because I only need to know the length of the x-axis from the centre of the object. Thank you very much once again, you have been an amazing help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had to post code so I had to make this an answer.

So I tried your method 0x141E, and it worked perfectly. The only problem I am having is that whenever the angle is not a multiple of 0.5PI it seems to calculate improperly. Maybe its just the way that I coded it though. The goal of my code was to place one object right beside another by measuring the distance between a left most, middle point of one object with the other objects right most, middle point. This way they would be touching left side with right side... Side-by-Side basically. I placed one object first and added the second using your given algorithm, but the result as I stated above got a little funky in between angles divisible by 0.5 PI. Here's what I've done, it should work if you import the code straight into XCode if you want to see what I am talking about (I'm sorry but I don't have enough rep to attach images or I would give a screenshot):

```
//This is the MyScene implementation file
@interface MyScene()
{
    SKSpriteNode *_object1;
    SKSpriteNode *_object2;
}
@end

@implementation MyScene
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if(self = [super initWithSize:size]
    {
        object1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(10,5)];
        [self addChild:object1];
        //The wait is just to make it feel smoother and not so sudden when starting up the simulator
        SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration: 2.5f];
        SKAction *rotate = [SKAction rotateByAngle:0.25*M_PI duration:2.0f];
        SKAction *addObject = [SKAction runBlock:^{
            _object2 = [spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(10,5)];

            //I set the rotation of the second object to the rotation of the first so they will always be touching side-by-side
            _object2.zRotation = _object1.zRotation;

            //I used the full width and heigth rather than half to save time. The two ojects are of equal width and height so instead of finding both distances and adding them together I just doubled the distance
            CGFloat r = sqrtf(_object2.frame.size.width*_object2.frame.size.width+_object2.frame.size.height*_object2.frame.size.height);
            CGFloat x = r*cosf(_object2.zRotation);
            CGFloat y = r*sinf(_object2.zRotation);

            object2.position = CGPointMake(_object2.position.x + x, _object2.position + y);

            [self addChild:_object2];
        }
        SKAction *seq = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, rotate, addObject]];
        [self runAction:seq];
    }
}
@end
```

Thank you again for all of your help thus far, and thank you even more for all of your potential future help.